Drain on a new Koehler bathroom faucet won’t open the drain to let water out
The drain that is opened and closed from behind the faucet won’t open the drain help

With no detail and no pictures, all we can suggest is that the linkage needs to be adjusted to work correctly. Can't tell you how to do that if we can't see what's not connected properly under the sink now.

Use a flash light and go under the sink, till you see the rods.
One goes straight down from the knob above.
Then it connects to a horizontal rod that lifts or lovers the drain cap.
Operate by hand and observe if the rods are moving.
Probably just loose screw that connects the vertical to the horizontal rod.
